# Why is the a:hover inside the div not working?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please explain why the a:hover is not working? I have declared an id for it but still it does not seem to work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #box1
            {
                width: 500px;
                height:300px;
                background-color: grey;
                border:4px solid pink;          
            }

            #id a:hover
            {
                z-index: 2;
                color:black;
                background-color: yellow;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

        </style>
    </head>     
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1 style="display:inline;padding-left:100px;padding-top:50px"> This is a heading</h1>
    <h2 style="display:inline-block;margin-left:10px;"> Another heading</h2>
    <div id="box1">
    <a id="link" href="http://google.com" style="position:block;letter-spacing:15px;margin-left:100px;
    font-size:50px;">GOOGLE</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oops my bad. BUt still does not work

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a selector called `id`. It's called `box1`. Change this:

```
#id a:hover
{
    z-index: 2;
    color:black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to this:

```
#box1 a:hover
{
    z-index: 2;
    color:black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/X6wWu/

Comment: can you please explain why is #link a:hover not working and why #box1 a:hover working? I don't seem to understand the difference.

Comment: If you want to use it on `<a>` you have to set it to `a#link:hover`. I'm not sure why though, I think it's because `<a>` is a defined tag, while `<div>` is somewhat freer. I'm not sure though. If my answer was correct I'd appreciate if you marked it as solved :-) Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between #link a:hover and a#link:hover?

Comment: @raiyan106 I think you should read this to understand CSS selectors : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: @simpe you should know that `z-index` is useless unless you use position. so  -1.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I just used the code from his example.

Comment: @KheemaPandey It's not really relative to the question so I don't think it deserves a -1. I provided an answer for the question, right? I'm not here to observe every single error in the original code.

Comment: hmm you are right.. no worries giving you +1 .. now smile :)

Answer (score 1):

@simpe answer is correct and working and you can also do it by

```
a#link:hover
            {
                z-index: 2;
                color:black;
                background-color: yellow;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```